# SQL joining on two columns with a variation on the first column

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have two tables:

Table 1: planA

```
ID    Date       Count
 3   2017-01-01     10
 2   2017-02-03     15
10   2017-01-30      8
```

Table 2: planB

```
ID    Date       Value
 3   2017-01-02     11
 2   2017-02-04     12
21   2017-01-30      3
 3   2017-02-03     33
```

What I want to do is to join the two tables on (ID and Date) columns.
However, on Date, I want to use the next day to the date on the table 1.
Therefore, the joined table should look like the following:

```
 PlanA.ID    PlanA.Date   PlanB.Date  PlanA.Count   PlanB.Value
  3        2017-01-01     2017-01-02       10            11
  2        2017-02-03     2017-02-04       15            12
```

Is this even possible?
Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: In your sample data "next date" is always the next day, but that's not necessarily so, correct? If there were no 2017-01-02 for ID 3, we'd pick 2017-01-03 as the next date after 2017-01-01, yes?

Comment: no, always next day. So if there is no 2017-01-02, it shouldn't pick any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

```
select
  PlanA.ID,
  PlanA.Date,
  PlanB.Date,
  PlanA.Count,
  PlanB.Value
from
  PlanA inner join PlanB
  on (
    PlanA.ID = PlanB.ID
    and
    PlanA.Date + INTERVAL 1 DAY = PlanB.Date
  )
```

if Date is a column of type date, `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` will return the next day of the one given, and then you can perform the join.

Comment: The date column looks like a valid MySQL's date format. Even when the date column is char or varchar type + INTERVAL 1 DAY should work just fine.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, MySQL should convert it to a date automatically... thanks!

Comment: Thanks @fthiella . Can I apply the same script for hive query as well by any chance?

Comment: Is there any other way without using INTERVAL as my hive version does not support INTERVAL?

Comment: Use `ADDDATE` with an integer for days: `ADDDATE(PlanA.Date, 1)`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate